# Facebook autopost link opens as map on phone

Tags: php, facebook, mobile

I cannot find even a hint of this issue anywhere on Google.
I have an Android and my other developer has an iPhone. We use
a Facebook autopost PHP script to autopost links to Facebook feeds. When
you open the feed via the mobile phones it opens a map first and you have to click
back. This happens on my phone with random things so I thought it was a phone issue.
But this is not happening with other posts we click on, just ours. When you create
a Facebook app is there some setting that enables/disables something like locations or maps 
that may be causing this issue?

Comment: To begin, can you share a sample link that is giving you this problem?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of code that surrounds your link ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to my particular problem was simple.
The link was correct on Facebook. The page it opened on our website
had a Google Map in the page footer. Once we removed that from the page, the
default Map application stopped opening first. Double check your page content!

Answer (score 0):

I was bringing in the map via Google's iframe. When I changed that to their v3 map api I no longer had this issue.

https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map